# SOAP monitoring using opennms

Tags: soap, monitoring, opennms

Is it possible to monitor a SOAP web service using opennms?if yes how?
i read about this in this link [BSFMonitor](http://www.opennms.org/wiki/BSFMonitor). i implemented "HTTP POST test to a SOAP endpoint" example as it says but still it's not coming up in my opennms service list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.this is for others who may face the same problem:
In opennms v1.4 and later you should add your service as detector to the "*Foreign Source Definition*" which is in ***Home / Admin / Provisioning Requisitions / Edit Foreign Source Definition*** in the web interface.that's it ;)